# Javascript "dragging" an image across a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

There's quite a few questions about this where the solution provided is to just set the `top left` and `top down` values of the image to the position of the mouse/touch, however what I want to do is to have an actual dragging movement. Regardless as to where on the canvas I press, if I drag my finger to the right x pixels, I want the image to move to the right x pixels. Same goes with left, up, and down.

I'm at a complete loss as to where to even start with this. I will be handling mobile touch events, so I feel like using `canvas.addEventListener('touchmove')` would be the best option, but I'm not sure.

I already have the canvas repainting and everything handled, just really need help with the logic for dragging the image in real time, instead of just snapping it into position.

Answer (score 1):

Get the point where the interaction starts (touchstart) and use it to calculate how much the finger moved on the screen (in the touchmove callback) and add it to the image position (also in touchmove).

PS: Also I recommend using something like PIXI JS for canvas/WebGL stuff ... unless you need a custom solution.

Comment: Trying to not include any more dependencies, as this is only for an image-cropper in my Hybrid application. Currently it uses buttons to move the image around, but I thought implementing touch gestures would be neat.  I would assume just take `currentTouch - lastTouch` vectors and then apply them to the fromTop/fromLeft values of the image?

Comment: @Hobbyist. Yes, calculate the amount of [deltaX,deltaY] the touch has changed from start to end and move the current image position by that deltaX and deltaY.